# Can't detect duplicate treeview nodes and assign it as child properly

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, treeview

I have a method that is used as a threadsafe callback to update a treeview. It takes two string parameters. The first is the passed data and the second is the IP of the host it checked.

I am trying to check whether or not the treeview currently contains the string containing the input string and if it doesn't than it is supposed to add it to the treeview as a parent node,  then add the ip string underneath as a child. Although if it does already contain that input string as a parent node than it should add only the Ip address underneath the parent that the data string matches.  So it basically sorts the ips. Each parent node will have multiple ips underneath.

My issue is that my method is adding each string as it's own parent regardless if it is a duplicate, which also means that it is not adding the IP of the duplicate input underneath the parent. Can anyone take a look and see where I am going wrong?

```
 public void UpdateScan(string input, string ip)
        {
            lock (outputTree)
            {
                outputTree.BeginUpdate();

                if (!(outputTree.Nodes.ContainsKey(input)))
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(input);
                    //Add our parent node
                    outputTree.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
                    //Add our child node
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add(ip);
                }
                else
                {
                    TreeNode[] treeNode = outputTree.Nodes.Find(input, true);
                    //Add only child node
                    foreach (var node in treeNode)
                    {
                        node.Nodes.Add(ip);
                    }
                }

                outputTree.EndUpdate();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working. By dynamically adding a key containing the data to the parent node, so I can then use that key to find the parents to add the correct children to them.

```
public void UpdateScan(string input, string ip)
{
    lock (outputTree)
    {
        outputTree.BeginUpdate();

        if (! outputTree.Nodes.ContainsKey(input))
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(input);
            treeNode.Name = input;
            //Add our parent node
            outputTree.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
            //Add our child node
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(ip);
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode[] found = outputTree.Nodes.Find(input, true);
            TreeNode newChild = new TreeNode(ip);
            //Add only child node
            found[0].Nodes.Add(newChild);
        }

        outputTree.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```